# PHP Regex to find first 3 match between slash

Tags: php, regex

I have a string like this:

```
$url = '/controller/method/para1/para2/';
```

Expected output:

```
Array(
   [0] => 'controller',
   [1] => 'method',
   [2] =>  array(
             [0] => 'para1', 
             [1] => 'para2'
           )
)
```

I am trying to build a regex to achieve this but not able to construct the pattern properly.
Please assist.

I tried to use explode function to split,

```
$split_url = explode('/',$url);
$controller = $split_url[1];
$method = $split_url[2];
unset($split_url[0]);
unset($split_url[1]);
unset($split_url[2]);

$para = $split_url;
```

But this is really not a great way of doing this and is prone to errors.

Comment: Have you tried anything so far? Please show your code. Also, what's happened to `para3`?

Comment: What happened to para3 ?

Comment: regexes with recursive matching? ouch..

Comment: Have you considered something less drastic? Something like, maybe, `explode('/', $array);`

Comment: What is wrong with explode approach for breaking apart this route?  Somewhere you will need logic (likely not within regex) to determine which portions of the route represent parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a slightly nasty method using explode:

```
$url = '/controller/method/para1/para2/para3/';
# get rid of leading and trailing slashes
$url = trim($url, '/');

$arr = explode('/', $url);

$results = array( $arr[0], $arr[1], array_slice($arr, 2) );

print_r($results);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => controller
    [1] => method
    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => para1
            [1] => para2
            [2] => para3
        )

)
```

It will work for any number of `para` elements.

And just to show that regexs are not scary, they're lovely fluffy friendly things, here's a regex version:

```
preg_match_all("/\/(\w+)/", $url, $matches);

$arr = $matches[1];
$results = array( $arr[0], $arr[1], array_slice($arr, 2) );
```

It's actually very easy to match this URL -- just search for `/` followed by alphanumeric characters (`\w+`).

Comment: This is what i was looking for. Superb. IF my url is '/controller', it still formats my output array. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

whithout regex:

```
$url = '/controller/method/para1/para2/para3/';

$arr = explode('/', trim($url, '/'));

$result = array_slice($arr, 0, 2);
$result[] = array_slice($arr, 2);

print_r($result);
```

Note: if you need to always have parameters at the same index (even if there is no method or parameters), you can change `$result[] = array_slice($arr, 2);` to `$result[2] = array_slice($arr, 2);`

Comment: Works great. Even if i dont include parameters it is working awesome ! Thanks.

Comment: Nice use of [`array_slice()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php).

Comment: @Sam: I always think about ham slice when i use it.

Answer (score 1):

How about something like:

```
$url = '/controller/method/para1/para2/para3/';
$regex = '~^/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/(?:(.*)/)?$~';

if(preg_match($regex, $url, $matches)) {
    $controller = $matches[1];
    $method = $matches[2];
    $parameters = explode('/', $matches[3]);
}
```

---

This [will capture](http://regex101.com/r/dW8jR2/1) 3 segments separated by a leading/trailing `/`. The 3rd segment of parameters can then be split with `explode()`. To get the array exactly like in your question:

```
$array = array($controller, $method, $parameters);

// Array
// (
//     [0] => controller
//     [1] => method
//     [2] => Array
//         (
//             [0] => para1
//             [1] => para2
//             [2] => para3
//         )
// )
```

Comment: Thanks Sam. This does work but if i dont include parameters (para1/para2...), it fails. With parameters, perfect !!

Comment: @AbhishekSaha I updated the regular expression to make parameters optional. I still require the leading and trailing `/` to be at the beginning/end of the string (easily changed, if you desire). Also, I'd probably go with the `explode()`/`array_splice()` method over `preg_match()` ;)

Comment: @AbhishekSaha this regex will allow for method and parameters to be optional: [`~^/([^/]+)(?:/([^/]+))?(?:/(.*?))?/$~`](http://regex101.com/r/dW8jR2/3)

Answer (score 0):

An alterate way of thinking about this is to actually parse your route to determine the controller and then pass the remaining route components off to the controller to determine what to do.

```
$url = '/controller/method/para1/para2/para3/';

$route_parts = explode('/', $url, '/')); // we don't need leading and trailing forward slashes
$controller_str = array_shift($route_parts);
$method_str = array_shift($route_parts);

// instantiate controller object be some means (a factory pattern shown here for demo purposes)
$controller = controllerFactory::getInstance($controller_str);
// set method on controller
$controller->setMethod($method_str);
// pass parameters to controller
$controller->setParams($route_parts);
// do whatever with controller
$controller->execute();
```

Comment: Thanks Mike. I do have a Router class which does a lot of stuff for me. Works pretty much like you showed.